# Reading all file names in a directory

Tags: c++, windows, file

I am trying to read all file names present in a  particular directory. I have made a program in C++ but this only prints the files directly in this directory. I want all the files which are also present in the subdirectory.

I have written a program in c++ which prints the file names in a directory but I want all file names in subdirectory also.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <dirent.h>
using namespace std;

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#ifndef WIN32
#include <unistd.h>
#endif

#ifdef WIN32
#define stat _stat
#endif

int main ()
{
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *ent;
    if ((dir = opendir ("c:\\test")) != NULL) {
        /* print all the files and directories within directory */
        while ((ent = readdir (dir)) != NULL) {
            printf ("%s\n", ent->d_name);
        }
        closedir (dir);
    } else {
        /* could not open directory */
        perror ("");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
}
```

**Actual result**:1.Printing file names which are directly in the directory and printing the subdirectory name.

**Expected**: I want instead of printing subdirectory name the program should print the names of files in that subdirectory.

Comment: You need to write a *recursive* function. It's a common task, I'm sure you can google an answer.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/recursive_directory_iterator

Comment: For instance this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9138866/c-list-all-directories-and-subdirectories-within-in-linux

Comment: @john thanks for this ...but this is for linux i want it for windows...

Comment: I have code for same requirement on my github repo. you can check it out here
https://github.com/mshingote/List-of-files-and-folders/blob/master/Enum_Files_and_Folders/Enum_Files_and_Folders/Main.cpp

Comment: @JohnWick1 The logic is identical on windows and linux. The API being used, opendir, readdir, closedir etc is also identical to your code. I'm sure you can translate any minor differences between the two platforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using windows OS then you can run below code to get a list of files in the provided directory.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <TCHAR.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void Enum(TCHAR root[0xFF])
{
    HANDLE hFind;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA wfd;
    TCHAR GeneralPath[0xFF];
    TCHAR AgainFolder[0xFF];
    TCHAR FileFullPath[0xFF];

    _stprintf(GeneralPath, _T("%s\\*.*"), root);
    hFind = FindFirstFile(GeneralPath, &wfd);

    if(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE==hFind)
        return;

    do
    {
        if( wfd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY ) //Checking Founded File Attribute is it File or Folder/Directory
        {
            if( !_tcscmp(wfd.cFileName, _T(".")) || !_tcscmp(wfd.cFileName, _T("..")) ) //if Founded directory is same(.) or parent(..) then ignore them
                continue;
            _stprintf(AgainFolder, _T("%s\\%s"), root, wfd.cFileName);
            Enum(AgainFolder); //Recursion because folder is inside another folder
        }
        else
        {
            _stprintf(FileFullPath, _T("%s\\%s"), root, wfd.cFileName); //  "Folder\\fileName.extension"
            _tprintf(_T("%s\n"),FileFullPath); 
        }

    }while(FindNextFile(hFind, &wfd));

    CloseHandle(hFind);
    hFind=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
}
int main()
{
    TCHAR Folder[0xFF]=_T("c:\\windows");
    Enum(Folder);
    return 0;
}
```

If you want to access complete visual studio solution you can clone [this](https://github.com/mshingote/List-of-files-and-folders) repository.

Comment: Hey i wanted to change the _T() this parameter with a string like ...............                     string s="C:\\test"    _T(s)  but this is showing error ....                                                       is there a way to do so...Please help...

Comment: you need to change project setting to use charset as ascii [
project properities -> configuration properities -> general -> charater set]

Comment: Then replace all _T(s)  to s

Answer (score 3):

If you have C++17 available, use `recursive_directory_iterator`. If not, you could use `dirent.h`-functions. Consider, for example, the following generic `traverseFiles`-function, which passes each file found then to a function that handles the file detected:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string>

void traverseFiles(const std::string &path, std::function<void(const std::string &)> cb) {
    if (auto dir = opendir(path.c_str())) {
        while (auto f = readdir(dir)) {
            if (f->d_name[0] == '.') continue;

            if (f->d_type == DT_DIR)
                traverseFiles(path + f->d_name + "/", cb);

            if (f->d_type == DT_REG)
                cb(path + f->d_name);
        }
        closedir(dir);
    }
}


void fileDetected(const std::string &f) {
    std::cout << "file:" << f << std::endl;
}


int main() {
    traverseFiles("c:/somestartdir", &fileDetected);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using C++17 **recursive_directory_iterator**:

```
#include <filesystem>

void ls_recursive(const std::filesystem::path& path) {
    for(const auto& p: std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator(path)) {
        std::cout << p.path() << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks dear...But i am new to programming can you please tell me what to pass as a parameter in function..

Comment: The `path`. And if you are on an older compiler that doesn't support C++17, your `dirent` approach is proper.

Comment: If your compiler doesn't support C++17 you could still search for a similar solution using boost - it's good to have cross-platform code in the long run and not attach yourself to WinAPI.

In C++14 it `recursive_directory_iterator` would be in `experimental/filesystem`.